# Increase size of text on click on button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How do I increase size of a dynamic text on click of a button in AS3, Adobe flash?
I have a dynamic text box (instance name is *damodara*).

I tried using the following code but it didn't work.

```
text_big.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    damodara.size +=  4;
}
```

I would be glad if you could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use set `setTextFormat` like this:

First, you need to have a`TextFormat` object. Like this:

```
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
```

then set the properties of that like this:

```
tf.size = 5; // or whatever you want here
```

then apply this format to your text:

```
myTextField.setTextFormat(tf);
```

Then, in the code you posted, replace `size+=5` with `damodara.setTextFormat(tf);`

Then to change it back you could either have a different `TextFormat` with a different `size` property or change the `size` property of *this* `TextFormat` and reapply the format doing `setTextFormat` again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot increase the size of the text, instead increase the font size while you click the button , then you are good to go.

```
textFormat = youtTextField.getTextFormat();
textFormat.size = int(textFormat.size)-1;
youtTextField.setTextFormat(textFormat);
```